# Linq grouping and max value

Tags: linq, max, grouping

I'm new to Linq. The following works, but can I also get the Max value of the Category's WorkOrderVersion(int) in a single query? Seems like I should be able to, but not sure how?

```
var results = from p in ExcelEstimateDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                          group p by p.Field<string>("Category") into g
                          orderby g.Key ascending
                          select new
                          {
                              Category = g.Key,
                              Properties = g
                          };

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Category: {item.Category}");

                foreach (DataRow dr in item.Properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"myLinqOutput: {dr["WorkOrderVersion"]}, {dr["Category"]}, {dr["SubCategory"]}");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could.

```
var results = from p in ExcelEstimateDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                          group p by p.Field<string>("Category") into g
                          orderby g.Key ascending
                          select new
                          {
                              Category = g.Key,
                              Properties = g,
                              MaxWorkOrderVersion = g.Max( x => x.Field<int>("WorkOrderVersion") )
                          };
```

Note: Since you are new to Linq it is OK that you are using Linq like this, on a DataTable (Linq To DataSet). However, later you would see this is the harder one. Linq To Objects, Linq To SQL, Linq to EF ... all are easier than doing that with a datatable.

AsEnumerable() there, is questionable, but since this is a DataTable, wouldn't matter much.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I will look into the others.

Comment: @mjordan, absolutely do. At least you would love the fact that you can use strongly typed values (thus intellisense) instead of easy to mistype string field names.